# DB Query dentro de um loop foreach está fazendo a minha página lenta

Tags: php, laravel

O código abaixo é utilizada para mostrar uma tabela com 15 resultados em uma página. Para isso, eu estou utilizando dois bancos de dados diferentes, um deles é um banco de dados wordpress e o outro é um banco de dados pessoal que eu criei.

A primeira query serve para pegar os values do banco de dados do wordpress, mas ele não pega os nomes de usuário, até mesmo porque o wordpress apenas armezena o ID de usuário nessa tabela. O único lugar onde eu cosigo adquirir o nome correto de usuário é no meu segundo banco de dados pessoal.

Para fazer isso, eu utilizo um loop foreach para substituir os IDs pelos nomes de usuário. Então, dentro do loop, há uma outra query para pegar esses nomes de usuário.

O meu problema é que, toda vez que eu carrego a página, eu estou rodando 16 db queries de uma vez só, e isso está realizando 16 requisições no banco de dados, dessa maneira, fazendo a minha página demorar para carregar.

```
public function index() {

    $posts = DB::connection('mysql2')
        ->table('wp_rocketsciencebrposts')
        ->select('ID', 'post_title', 'post_status', 'post_author', 'post_date')
        ->whereIn('post_status', ['publish', 'private'])
        ->where('post_type', 'post')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->paginate(15, ['*'], 'posts');

    $posts = compact('posts');

    foreach($posts['posts'] as &$value){

        //this DB Query is making my page slow, since it's inside this foreach loop, therefore, making 16 database requests
        $value->post_author = DB::connection('mysql')
            ->table('users')
            ->select('name')
            ->where('rsbwordpressid', $value->post_author)
            ->value('name');

    }

    return view('posts/posts', $posts);

}
```

Eu tenho certeza que a solução deve ser simples, porém eu não consigo pensar em uma estratégia de como colocar o segundo query fora do loop foreach, evitando assim, todas essas desnecessárias requisições ao banco de dados.

Ajuda ai!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa é a resposta que eu estava esperando ver:

```
public function index() {

    $posts = DB::connection('mysql2')
    ->table('wp_rocketsciencebrposts')
    ->select('ID', 'post_title', 'post_status', 'post_author', 'post_date')
    ->whereIn('post_status', ['publish', 'private'])
    ->where('post_type', 'post')
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->paginate(15, ['*'], 'posts');

    $user_ids = $posts->pluck('post_author')->toArray();

    $users = DB::connection('mysql')
    ->table('users')
    ->whereIn('rsbwordpressid', $user_ids)
    ->pluck('rsbwordpressid', 'name')
    ->toArray();

    $posts = compact('posts');

    $users = array_flip($users);

    foreach($posts['posts'] as $value) {

        $value->post_author = $users[$value->post_author];

    }

    return view('posts/posts', $posts)->with('mensagemSucesso', print_r($users) );

}
```